# TagSet::sym Error using Subscript

Tags: symbolic, warning-messages, syntax, subscript

I am a beginner to Mathematica and I am trying to get it to solve some equations of a function (vector) $B$ of three components, but first I want it to know that the derivates with respect to one coordinate (\theta) are always zero, so that whenever they are encountered later, that will taken into account.  I liked this method because I can associate such conditions with these components from the beginning (i.e. not have to worry about inserting them as rules later in each evaluation).

So I wrote:

```
B = {Subscript[B, r], Subscript[B, θ], Subscript[B, z]};
Subscript[B, θ] = 0;
Subscript[B, r] /: D[Subscript[B, r], θ] = 0;
Subscript[B, θ] /: D[Subscript[B, θ], θ] = 0;
Subscript[B, z] /: D[Subscript[B, z], θ] = 0;
```

But upon evaluation it gave me the errors:

[image: errors: recursion limit, tagSet too deep...]

Any help on how to solve this issue with simple explanation (so that I can understand as beginner) would be great. Thank you.

Comment: I noticed that if I remove the subscripts from the symbol B (so, if I write $B_{r}$ as $Br$ instead), the errors disappear! But this is a bit inconvenient, because I was hoping to be able to use the subscripts like in usual mathematical notation.

Comment: Good general advice is to [avoid subscripted symbols altogether](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/27951) for computation. Their visual allure notwithstanding, they often cause unexpected trouble, as you’ve just experienced.